# Pass variable to struct function

Tags: go, struct

```
type MultiplyStruct struct {
    Number1 int
}

func (m MultiplyStruct) Multiply() int {
    return m.Number1 * number2
}
```

how can I pass `number2` to the Multiply function? Would it be like this?

```
   var multiplier = MultiplyStruct(10)
   multiplier.Multiply(20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MultiplyStruct struct {
    Number1 int
}

func (m MultiplyStruct) Multiply(number2 int) int {
    return m.Number1 * number2
}

func main() {
    multipler := MultiplyStruct{Number1: 10}
    val := multipler.Multiply(20)
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

[On Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/In3lrtOmEL)

Answer (score 1):

Just an interesting addition to the correct answer. You can create a curried function without using a struct to store only an integer:

```
func Multiply(number1 int) (func(int) int) {
    return func(number2 int) int {
        return number1 * number2
    }
}

func main() {
    timesTen := Multiply(10)
    fmt.Println(timesTen(20))    // => 200
    timesTwo := Multiply(2)   
    fmt.Println(timesTwo(10))    // => 20

    fmt.Println(Multiply(2)(3))  // => 6
}
```